# Conversão de .FRM para .SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, backup

Estou com uma base de dados de 300MB e só tenho os arquivos FRM, MYI e MYD. Preciso converter primeiro os arquivos FRM para criar a estrutura das tabelas, já usei as seguintes ferramentas e métodos e não obtive sucesso:

https://recovery.twindb.com/

Erro: ERROR: Failed to correctly read the .frm file. Please try reading the file with the --diagnostic mode.

Tentei esse modo também:

```
     mysqlfrm --diagnostic "arquivo.frm" > "C:\table.sql"
```

Mensagem:

> WARNING: Cannot generate character set or collation names without the
>   --server option.  CAUTION: The diagnostic mode is a best-effort parse of the .frm file. As such, it may not identify all of the components
>   of the table correctly. This is especially true for damaged files. It
>   will also not read the default values for the columns and the
>   resulting statement may not be syntactically correct.  Reading .frm
>   file for cliente.frm:  The .frm file is a TABLE.

E esse:

```
  mysqlfrm –server=root:mypassword@localhost –port=3311 "<source/path>/mytable.frm" > "<destination/path>/recovered_mytable.sql"
```

Mensagem:

> ERRO: o processo "11892" não foi encontrado.

Answer (score 2):

Opa, consegui por aqui!

É só criar um database qualquer e criar uma tabela qualquer também.

Depois, ir nos arquivos que foram gerados:

C:\xampp\mysql\data\NOME DO DATABASE QUE CRIOU

Apagar todos os arquivos dessa pasta, depois, colar os arquivos que você tem: FRM, MYD e MYI, restartar o serviço Mysql, e tudo feito!

**ATENÇÃO:**

Esse método só funciona se for mesma versão (MYSQL), e com os mesmos parâmetros gerais. A maneira mais adequada de transportar bases de dados é gerando uma DUMP.

Comment: Que bom que resolveu seu caso, mas isso só funciona se for mesma versão, e com os mesmos parâmetros gerais. A maneira mais adequada de transportar bases de dados é o dump mesmo.

Comment: Sim, mas não tinha acesso nenhum ao BD. Era o único recurso possível.

Comment: Sim, eu entendi isso, mas avisei, pq pode vir outro leitor aqui e tentar o mesmo, e se complicar com corrupção de dados.

Comment: @GuilhermeLuis, acho que vale a pena sinalizar na resposta isso que [@Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70/bacco) mencionou..

Comment: Sinalizei lá, alguém poderia marcar como correta né?